# R flexdashboard with shiny - Sidebar

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm trying to create a flexdashboard using r with a similar format to [this page](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#multiple_pages).

I used a flexdashboard with Shiny.

````
---
title: "title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(lubridate)
library(viridis)
library(plotly)
library(tidytext)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r global, include=FALSE}
# read global data
```

```{r wrangling-data}
```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
# shiny inputs defined here
```

Introduction
=====================================  

### Intro

```{r}
```

Data
=====================================     

```{r}
```

Conclusion
=====================================     

```{r}
```
````

This results in the menu items still showing on the top navigation bar.

However, I want to move the navigation babe onto the left side, [like this](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#multiple_pages) and also include accordion sub-menus on the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a level (just a sequence of dashes `--`). Try this code:

````
---
title: "title"
output: 
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(lubridate)
library(viridis)
library(plotly)
library(tidytext)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r global, include=FALSE}
# read global data
```

```{r wrangling-data}
```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
# shiny inputs defined here

```
Some text added

-------------------------------------

Introduction
=====================================  

### Intro

```{r}
```

Data
=====================================     

```{r}
```

Conclusion
=====================================     

```{r}
```
````

Hope it helps.